# accordion doesn't go open when using <a name>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I usually get my codes from: https://www.w3schools.com.
There is also an accordion to take with this code

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion"> </button>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

However when I use `<a href="#link.html">link</a>` -> to `<a name="link"></a>`
The accordion doesn't jump open but stays closed.
Does someone know how to open the accordion if someone links a link which has content inside an accordion.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your css in place, kindly tweak the following line from

```
this.classList.toggle("active");
this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
```

to

```
this.classList.toggle("active");
let sibling = this.nextElementSibling;
if(sibling.style.display == "block") { sibling.style.display == "none"; }
else {sibling.style.display == "block"}
```

let me know if this helps

Comment: Doesn't work at all, now the accordion doesn't go open at all.

Comment: http://atlanticwave.co/anchor-links-open-demo <- I want it like that demo